# I don't understand why Beautiful Soup gives first link not second, and first select_one won't work as second one does

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am doing some Python coding with Beautiful Soup. I got it working now, but I have no idea why it works, and I am pretty sure this will cause me to run into problems as I go forward. Can anyone help me understand this?

I have downloaded an HTML file that has hundreds of items in a table. Here is one table item:

```
<td class="gsc_a_t">
  <a href="www.the_first_link.com" class="gsc_a_at">The title that goes with the link</a>
  <div class="gs_gray">author1, author 2, author 3</div>
  <div class="gs_gray">
    ”source for the item”
    <span class="gs_oph">, 2020</span>
  </div>
</td>
<td class="gsc_a_c">
  <a href="www.the_second_link.com” class="gsc_a_ac gs_ibl">2</a>
</td>
<td class="gsc_a_y">
  <span class="gsc_a_h gsc_a_hc gs_ibl">2020</span>
</td>
```

The following is the code for each table item:

```
for i in table_results:
    item = i
    first_link = i.a['href']
    title = i.a.text
    authors = i.select_one('.gs_gray').text
    source = i.select('.gs_gray')[-1].text
    second_link = i.select_one('.gsc_a_ac')['href']
    citations = i.select_one('.gsc_a_ac').text
    year = i.select_one('.gsc_a_y').text
```

When I run it, I want `first_link` to record the first link and `second_link` to get the second one. They ARE doing that ... but I don't know why. Why doesn't the `first link` capture the `i.a['href']` from the second link instead of the first link? Both have the same `<a href=" ... ></a>` constructions. Also, I tried doing `first_link = i.select_one('.gsc.a.at')['href']` similar to the way it captures the second link, and that does not work. It references "return self.attrs[key]" and says KeyError: 'href'

I have looked at the Beautiful Soup documentation, but I am not understanding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why doesn't the first link capture the i.a['href'] from the second link instead of the first link?

I don't have the reference handy, but using dot notation selects the **first** element with the particular name. It's the equivalent of using `select_one` with css selectors. Which leads us to:

> `first_link = i.select_one('.gsc.a.at')['href']` ... says KeyError: 'href'

That's because `select_one` selects the first element meeting the stated condition (in this case, having the specified class attribute value). In the html, the first element meeting that condition is the first `td`, which itself doesn't have a `href` attribute. What you are looking for is the child `a` element of that `td`:

```
i.select_one('.gsc_a_t a')['href']
```